# Compare two strings regardless of case size in perl

Tags: perl, compare, equals

is there anyway to compare two strings regardless of case size?
For Example

```
"steve" eq "STevE"   <----- these would match
"SHOE" eq "shoe"
```

You get the picture

Answer (score 21, accepted):

yes - use `uc()` (upper-case function; see http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/uc.html )

```
$ perl -e 'print uc("steve") eq uc("STevE"); print "\n";'
1
$ perl -e 'print uc("SHOE") eq uc("shoe"); print "\n";'          
1
$ perl5.8 -e 'print uc("SHOE") eq uc("shoe1"); print "\n";'

$
```

You can obviously use `lc()` as well.

If you want the actual "eq" operator to be case insensitive, it might be possible using overloads but I don't think that's what you are asking for - please clarify your question if that's the case. Nor is it a great idea if you do want that, IMHO - too fragile and leads to major possible hard to trace and debug bugs.

Also, it's an overkill in your specific case where you just want equality, but Perl regular expressions also have case-independent modifyer "i"

Answer (score 16):

A couple of ways to do this:

- Use the [`lc`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lc.html) or `uc` operator, which converts both strings to lower or upper case respectively:

  ```
  lc "steve" eq lc "STevE";
  ```
- A simple regex will do just as well:

  ```
  'steve' =~ /^STevE$/i;
  ```

Comment: Reread the smartmatch docs; that last one is falling into the Any~~Regex case which means the left site is stringified and matched using the right.  On 5.10.1, it appears to be doing `"(?i-xsm:steve)" =~ /STevE/i` when I would have expected `( $_ =~ /steve/i ) =~ /STevE/i`, but neither is appropriate here.

Comment: N.B. smartmatch on 5.10.0 has design flaws (that were fixed in 5.10.1) and shouldn't be used.

Comment: maybe I made my comment too complicated.  succinctly, the ~~ doesn't work for this.  For instance, /steve/i ~~ /x/i is true.

Comment: You should anchor your regexp, `'steven' =~ /STevE/i;` will also be true.

Answer (score 5):

According to perldoc (http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fc.html), it's better to use

```
fc("steve") eq fc("STevE")
```

Don't forget to add this line before first use of `fc`:

```
use feature 'fc';
```

Comment: Good point. Basically `fc` is similar to `uc`/`lc` but able to handle non-ASCII characters.

Comment: `uc` and `lc` works well with unicode characters too.