# Perl String Compare Not Working

Tags: perl

Below is my Perl Program:

```
my $var1='perfp2u1@vanlync2k13.com';
my $var2='PerfP2U1@vanlync2k13.com';
if($var1 eq $var2){
    print "match";
}
else{
    print "no match";
}
```

OUTPUT IS:
`no match`

I have no idea why the program is not working properly?????
I expect an output "match", for the above program.

Below is my straberry perl version details (OS: windows 7).

```
D:>perl -version
This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 2 (v5.16.2) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-t
hread

Copyright 1987-2012, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.
```

Comment: Why would you expect "match" when the strings clearly aren't equal?

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399129/compare-two-strings-regardless-of-case-size-in-perl

Comment: `eq` is case sensitive, so your strings don't match because `$var2` has capital `P`s.

Comment: It seems self-evident to me. Your output is `no match` because the strings don't match. Your program is working properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want case insensitive matching, just use [`lc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lc.html)

```
my $var1 = 'perfp2u1@vanlync2k13.com';
my $var2 = 'PerfP2U1@vanlync2k13.com';

if(lc $var1 eq lc $var2){
    print "match";
} else{
    print "no match";
}
```

Comment: For case-insensitive comparisons, you actually want to use `fc($var1) eq fc($var2)`, but it's only available as a builtin starting in 5.16. `lc($var1) eq lc($var2)` will almost always work, so it's suitable elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the introduction to [`fc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fc.html).  One of the companies that I considered applying to recently does a lot of unicode work, but I've yet to really tackle the subject.  I just know enough that it's one helluva headache, from those that work there.

Comment: OMG, how could I miss that the case was not matching!!! I spend half a day trying to find out what went wrong!!! My goodness & I ended up asking a STUPID question in open forum!!! Well... (really frustrated with myself)..., but THANKS A LOT that you've pointed out it, else I whould've spent more time trying trying to figure out what went wrong :).

Answer (score 1):

The Perl `eq` operator is case-sensitive, and I am surprised you think it should behave any differently.

To do a *case-insensitive* comparison you can convert both strings to lower case (or upper case - it doesn't matter as long as both are modified in the same way) before you do the comparison.

Like this

```
my $var1 = 'perfp2u1@vanlync2k13.com';
my $var2 = 'PerfP2U1@vanlync2k13.com';

if (lc $var1 eq lc $var2){
    print 'match';
}
else {
    print 'no match';
}
```

**output**

```
match
```

Comment: For case-insensitive comparisons, you actually want to use `fc($var1) eq fc($var2)`, but it's only available as a builtin starting in 5.16. `lc($var1) eq lc($var2)` will almost always work, so it's suitable elsewhere.

Comment: @ikegami: That's only necessary for non-ASCII applications. It also requires a `use feature 'fc'` or `use 5.016` to enable it.

Comment: OMG, how could I miss that the case was not matching!!! I spend half a day trying to find out what went wrong!!! My goodness & I ended up asking a STUPID question in open forum!!! Well... (really frustrated with myself)..., but THANKS A LOT that you've pointed out it, else I would have spent more time trying trying to figure out what went wrong :).

Comment: @SaurabhChakrabarty: Don't worry - we all do it!

Comment: I don't know how I did miss the cases of the two strings at that time while posting the question but later I did find it myself. But anyway, thank you for your answers :).